# Cufon Hover & Change of font syntax

Tags: javascript, cufon

Could someone help me rewrite this syntax below to get it right.

I want the font to be replaced by my font whilst accepting the :hover so my button will change when i hover over it.

```
 Cufon('button', {
    fontFamily: 'Disgrunged A',
    hover: {
        color: '#ed1c24'
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to add button to hoverables list

```
Cufon('button', {
    fontFamily: 'Disgrunged A',
    hover: {
        color: '#ed1c24'
    },
    hoverables: { button:true }
 });
```

Ref: [Cufon API](http://wiki.github.com/sorccu/cufon/api)

> **hoverables**
>   Defines which elements
>   :hover is used with. Defaults to links
>   only as IE6 can’t handle anything
>   else.
>   **example** : { tag: true, .. }
>   **default** : { a: true }

Comment: Thanks mate, i put this in about ten minutes ago :p  Thank you for your efforts.  Its spot on.

Answer (score 0):

i don't know cufon, but i think the syntax has to be like this:

```
 Cufon.replace('button:hover', {
    fontFamily: 'Disgrunged A'
 });
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didnt work :(  That would indicate the cufon only be applied on hover.